# How to make next element click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating elements dynamically using following code

```
elem = $("<div class='col-sm-3'>");
 elem.prepend($("<input type='submit' style='display:none'>"));
 image = $('<img >');
 image.attr('src', prop[j]);
 elem.append(image);
```

Not getting how on click of image submit button can be fired

Comment: _I want_ So whats stopping you? Go ahead

Comment: do you want to trigger a form submit? because then you can do `image.on('click',function(){$('form').submit();})`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jquery on` to bind click function with image id. You need to set an id on image and pass it instead of image_id. On function is bind on future elements so you do not need to click on submit button you can directly submit form.

```
$( "#image_id" ).on( "click", function() {
  $("#form_id").submit();
});
```

PS: 
If you have any click bind on submit button than use

```
$( "#foo" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that this should be in the same `form` tag which you want to submit

as you know you are creating dynamic elements, this needs to be delegate function check the code.

```
elem = $("<div class='col-sm-3'>");
elem.prepend($("<input type='submit' style='display:none'>"));
image = $('<img id="img">');
image.attr('src', prop[j]);
elem.append(image);

$(document).on("click","#img" function(){
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```